# Windows 8.1 Pro - CPU Usage Stays at 100%

Tags: performance, cpu, windows-8.1, cpu-usage, task-manager

About an hour ago, I noticed that my laptop had gotten noticeably slower. My laptop is extremely fast, so this extreme decrease in performance prompted me to look at the task manager. In the task manager, the histogram showed that my CPU usage was at a steady 100%. I wasn't sure what the cause of the problem was, so I decided to reboot my computer. After doing so, I went into the task manager, and in a few moments, the histogram was once again showing a steady 100% CPU usage. I have no explanation for the problem, as it seems to have started on its own. I am using my mom's laptop now to write this. Could someone please explain to me what could have caused the problem, and more importantly, what I can do to solve it? My laptop has conveniently turned into a brick right before school starts back up again for me when I need it the most.

**Edit: So I powered on my laptop on which this problem is occurring, and during the boot-up process, I unplugged the display cable for my double monitor setup. After booting up, I opened the Task Manager, and saw that everything was just fine. My CPU was not showing a steady 100% anymore. A few seconds later, I got these two messages, in order in which they are displayed...**

[image: MySQL Error 1]

[image: MySQL Error 2]

**I checked in my task tray (or whatever they call that thing next to the clock), and MySQL notifier, which normally starts on its own, was not open. I tried starting it manually, but I got the same result. It appears that the issue with my CPU had something to do with it. Now I just have a different problem: something is wrong with MySQL. Even though the question was not originally about this, I would appreciate it if someone would help me solve the problem anyway.**

Comment: You looked at task manager, why did you not look at the list in task manager to see which process was using the 100% cpu?

Comment: Switch to the *Processes* tab and [sort by CPU usage](http://i.imgur.com/9NOMrPn.png).

Comment: I looked to see what was eating the CPU, and I did not see anything out of the norm. I saw one program that had to services running, both of the same name. When I tried to stop the service that as using 30% CPU, I got an 'access denied' message. Even when I do manage to stop a svchost that is using 5 to 10 percent, I still get a listing of 100%. I was just using Google Chrome, surfing the internet when the decrease in performance became noticeable. I opened several new tabs for something I was doing, and things just slowed down. What can I do about this?

Comment: `I was using Google Chrome, surfing the internet when the decrease in performance became noticeable. I opened several new tabs for something I was doing, and things just slowed down. What can I do about this?` Not open them. You do realize that browsing the Internet now requires a pretty hefty computer right? People used to sell their old, obsolete systems as “browsing computers” back in the days of simple, static HTML pages, but today’s Internet requires some serious power to support Flash, JavaScript, and all that junk. Opening several tabs (especially beefy pages) *will* kill performance.

Comment: do this http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD and upload the generated file

Comment: @Synetech At first I thought that you were being sarcastic, but you have a point.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have already fixed the CPU problem, but now I need to fix the issue with MySQL.

Comment: I don't use MySQL, so I can't help.

Comment: `At first I thought that you were being sarcastic` I wish I were, I really do, but unfortunately even simple web browsing now requires a modern system. Maybe not quite as powerful as for 3D gaming, but certainly enough that my six-year-old system can’t handle more than one or two new tabs with JavaScript at a time without pegging the CPU at 100% for a minute or two, and even a two-year-old laptop struggles with more than three or four at a time. `:-(` Flash has *always* had horrible performance and they never seem to bother trying to fix that, and yet it’s become ubiquitous, even in ads.

Comment: @Synetech Now you are beginning to remind me why I put ad blocker on my old computer, even though I think it is unethical. I just uninstalled it, and you are right. All of those flash banners are slowing things down for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I powered on my laptop on which this problem is occurring, and during the boot-up process, I unplugged the display cable for my double monitor setup. After booting up, I opened the Task Manager, and saw that everything was just fine. My CPU was not showing a steady 100% anymore. A few seconds later, I got these two messages, in order in which they are displayed...

[image]

[image]